# Can multiple designers work together?

Tags: workflow, designers, best-practice

I've been wondering if it is successful to have two or more designers work on the same graphic design.

I have tried a few times, but I ended up with a design that was not good enough, even though we are good individually. I think that's because everyone has their own touch.

Should I ask to design by myself, or should I learn to do it successfully with a group?

Comment: What did your process of working with other designers look like? What about the finished design was not good?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, more than one designer can work together.

Can more than one designer working together produce a better design solution than individuals working on their own? Hard to say. It really depends on a number of things.

In my experience, when you get the right group of designers together, things can be much more productive as a group. It requires a certain type of ego for it all to work smoothly, but it can definitely be done.

I've worked in design firms that did the solo model (you 3 designers each go and do your own thing, and then we'll pick one of the 3 to go with) and I've worked in firms that do the group model (everyone come up with ideas, let's get together, brainstorm, iterate, assign tasks, delegate, etc.).

I personally prefer the latter. Being able to think through design problems out loud makes the process much more streamlined, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You need a good Creative Director to keep everything working together. That CD might be one of the designers on the project or an overseer one step removed from the execution.

It is possible to work successfully as collaborators without a "head", but rare. You need a team that has an excellent understanding of each other's approach and the common goals for the project.